# Get default value for Managed metadata column

Tags: managed-metadata, jsom

How can I get the default value of a Managed metadata column.
I'm trying to do:

```
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(url);
web = ctx.get_web();
lists = web.get_lists();

ctx.load(lists,'Include(Title,BaseType,Fields.Include(Title,InternalName,DefaultValue,TypeAsString))');
ctx.executeQueryAsync(function(){onQuerySucceeded(myParam)}, onQueryFailed);
```

But the default value when the column is `TaxonomyFieldType` is empty. How can I get the value? I know that the column has a default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was curious about why it didn't work so started testing my self. I got it finally working, using an example from msdn (https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/office/hh185009(v=office.14).aspx). Try using following code to see if you it return a default value:

```
function retrieveAllListsAllFields() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
    var collList = oWebsite.get_lists();

    this.listInfoArray = clientContext.loadQuery(collList, 
        'Include(Title,Fields.Include(Title,InternalName, DefaultValue))');

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
        Function.createDelegate(this, this._onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {

    var listInfo = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < this.listInfoArray.length; i++) {

        var oList = this.listInfoArray[i];
        var collField = oList.get_fields();

        var fieldEnumerator = collField.getEnumerator();

        while (fieldEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var oField = fieldEnumerator.get_current();          
                listInfo += '\nList: ' + oList.get_title() + 
                    '\n\tField Title: ' + oField.get_title() + 
            '\n\tField DefaultValue: ' + oField.get_defaultValue();
        }
    }
    console.log(listInfo);
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js", "SP.ClientContext", function () {
   retrieveAllListsAllFields();
});
```

I tested on SharePoint Online with a managed metadata field and it return the default value in this format: 5;#testLevel2|8e5ede37-1722-4b4e-928c-8e15b52a2bd2

Comment: No, this is exactly what is not working for me. It's returning "" as DefaultValue for me

Comment: I even try to get the values for an specific library and I'm having the same issue

Comment: The problem was that the defaults were assigned to the root folder instead of the library